# Verifying halting-problem on self-implemented pseudo-assembly

Tags: c++, recursion, assembly, halting-problem

I wrote a very simple implementation of what could be a similarity to Assembly/machine code.

It is even capable of recursion as in this example:

```
9 6
IFEQ R0,0
RET 1
ENDIF
MOV R1,R0
SUB R1,1
CALL R1
MOV R2,R9
MUL R2,R0
RET R2
```

Output: 720 (factorial of 6)

Description:

```
9 = Program Lines
6 = Program Input. Will be set to registry R0 value at class construction
CALL = calls the program again with the passed value (recursion)
RET = returns the program with the specified value. Sets registry R9 value to output value.

R0 to R9 -> general purpose registry.
R0 - program input value
R9 - program output value
```

-edit: Program commands:
`MOV, ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD, IFEQ, IFNEQ, IFG, IFGE, IFL, IFLE, ENDIF, CALL, RET`

However the program can enter into infinite loop/recursion. e.g:

```
2 0
CALL 10
RET 1 //will never be reached
```

**How do I verify whether *MY* program will enter into an infinite loop/recursion?**

Here's my implementation, don't know whether it's necessary, but just in case you need. (It's the whole code... hope you don't mind).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string> //std::getline
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

namespace util
{
    template<typename I>I readcin(I& input) {
        std::cin >> input;
        std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore();
        return input;
    }
    template<typename I, typename...O> I readcin(I& input, O&... others) {
        readcin(input);
        return readcin(others...);
    }
}

//operations
enum OP
{
    MOV, ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD,
    IFG, IFL,
    IFEQ, IFGE, IFLE,
    IFNEQ,
    CALL,
    RET,
    ENDIF,
};
std::map<std::string, OP> OPTABLE
{
    {"MOV", MOV}, {"ADD", ADD}, {"SUB", SUB}, {"MUL", MUL}, {"DIV", DIV}, {"MOD", MOD},
    {"RET", RET},
    {"IFG", IFG}, {"IFL", IFL},
    {"IFNEQ", IFNEQ}, {"IFEQ", IFEQ}, {"IFGE", IFGE}, {"IFLE", IFLE},
    {"CALL", CALL},
    {"ENDIF", ENDIF}
};
//registry index
enum RI
{
    R0, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, RI_MAX
};
std::map<std::string, RI> RITABLE =
{
    {"R0", R0}, {"R1", R1}, {"R2", R2}, {"R3", R3}, {"R4", R4}, {"R5", R5},
    {"R6", R6}, {"R7", R7}, {"R8", R8}, {"R9", R9}
};

struct Instruction
{
    OP op;
    RI r1;
    int r2value;
    Instruction() = delete;
    Instruction(OP operation, RI firstRegister, int _2ndRegValue = -1)
    {
        op = operation;
        r1 = firstRegister;
        r2value = _2ndRegValue;
    }
};


class Assembly
{

private:
    int REG[RI::RI_MAX] {0};
    int GetRegistryValue(RI ri) const { return REG[ri]; }
    void SetRegistryValue(RI ri, int val) { REG[ri] = val; }

    enum CMP_FLAG{ CMP_FAIL, CMP_OK };
    CMP_FLAG flag { CMP_OK };
    CMP_FLAG GetFlag() const { return flag; }
    void SetFlag(bool setFlag) { flag = static_cast<CMP_FLAG>(setFlag); }

    std::vector<std::string> programLines;

    OP ExtractOP(const std::string& line);
    RI ExtractRI(const std::string& line, OP op);
    int Extract2ndRIval(const std::string& line, OP op);
public:
    void addCommand(const std::string& line) { programLines.push_back(line); }
    void Execute();

    Assembly() = delete;
    Assembly(int inputValue) { REG[R0] = inputValue; }
    int ReturnValue() const { return REG[R9]; }
private:
    //recursion only
    Assembly(int inputValue, const std::vector<std::string>& progLines) {
        REG[R0] = inputValue;
        programLines = progLines;
        this->Execute();
    }
};

OP Assembly::ExtractOP(const std::string& line)
{
    std::istringstream issline{ line };
    std::string operation;
    issline >> operation;

    return OPTABLE[operation];
}

RI Assembly::ExtractRI(const std::string& line, OP op)
{
    auto space = line.find(' ');
    if(op <= IFNEQ){
        auto comma = line.find(',');
        return RITABLE[std::string(line.begin() + space + 1, line.begin() + comma)];
    }
    return RI_MAX;
}

int Assembly::Extract2ndRIval(const std::string& line, OP op)
{
    if(op == ENDIF) {
        return -1;
    }

    std::size_t spaceOrComma;
    if(op == CALL || op == RET) {
        spaceOrComma = line.find(' ');
    } else {
        spaceOrComma = line.find(',');
    }

    std::string opval = std::string(line.begin() + spaceOrComma + 1, line.end());
    auto it = RITABLE.find(opval);
    if(it != RITABLE.end()){
        return this->REG[it->second];
    }
    auto num = std::atoi(opval.c_str());
    return num;
}

void Assembly::Execute()
{
    for(const std::string& line : programLines)
    {
        OP op = ExtractOP(line);
        RI r1 = ExtractRI(line, op);
        int r2value = Extract2ndRIval(line, op);

        Instruction command ( op, r1, r2value );

        if(GetFlag() == CMP_FAIL)
        {
            if(command.op == ENDIF){
                SetFlag(CMP_OK);
            }
            continue;
        }

        switch(command.op)
        {
            case MOV: { SetRegistryValue(command.r1, command.r2value); } break;
            case ADD: { SetRegistryValue(command.r1, REG[command.r1] + command.r2value); } break;
            case SUB: { SetRegistryValue(command.r1, REG[command.r1] - command.r2value); } break;
            case MUL: { SetRegistryValue(command.r1, REG[command.r1] * command.r2value); } break;
            case DIV: { SetRegistryValue(command.r1, REG[command.r1] / command.r2value); } break;
            case MOD: { SetRegistryValue(command.r1, REG[command.r1] % command.r2value); } break;

            case IFEQ:  { SetFlag(GetRegistryValue(command.r1) == command.r2value); } break;
            case IFNEQ: { SetFlag(GetRegistryValue(command.r1) != command.r2value); } break;
            case IFG:   { SetFlag(GetRegistryValue(command.r1) > command.r2value); } break;
            case IFL:   { SetFlag(GetRegistryValue(command.r1) < command.r2value); } break;
            case IFGE:  { SetFlag(GetRegistryValue(command.r1) >= command.r2value); } break;
            case IFLE:  { SetFlag(GetRegistryValue(command.r1) <= command.r2value); } break;

            case RET:
            {
                SetRegistryValue(R9, command.r2value);
                return;
            }break;

            //oh boy!
            case CALL:
            {
               // std::cout << "value to call:" << command.r2value << std::endl;
                Assembly recursion(command.r2value, this->programLines);
                SetRegistryValue(R9, recursion.ReturnValue());
            }break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int pl, input;
        util::readcin(pl, input);
        if(pl == 0){
            break;
        }

        Assembly Asm(input);
        for(auto i=0; i<pl; ++i)
        {
            std::string line;
            std::getline(std::cin, line);
            Asm.addCommand(line);
        }
        Asm.Execute();

        std::cout << Asm.ReturnValue() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How do I verify whether a program will enter into an infinite loop/recursion?* For a Turing-complete language, [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) was famously proven to be undecidable in the general case.  Of course you can write a program that can prove halting or non-halting for some simple-enough cases, e.g. if the entire machine state (including memory) matches an earlier state, so you can in theory eventually detect any non-halting program on a finite machine.

Comment: I'm not sure if your assembly language is Turing-complete, though; how does `call` know where to jump?  In normal assembly languages, the `call` instruction takes a target address (as a symbol or a register holding a pointer) and sets the program counter to that value (as well as saving a return address somewhere, on the stack or a link register). Function args are passed in other regs or memory as per the calling convention.

Comment: If the CPU in your computer can determine that it's stuck in an infinite loop, sounds like that would make it a lot easier to learn C++. Unfortunately, that's just a pipe dream.

Comment: @PeterCordes The call instruction just jumps to the start of the program with all the registers initialized to 0 except R0 which is set to the value of the operand.  Also this problem is worse than the halting problem, as it's asking to determine whether the program halts on all inputs, rather than just one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Halting_on_all_inputs

Comment: @RossRidge: that's what I thought, which makes it much more limited than if you could call *another* function like a normal program.  Except it seems to be the only backwards branch.  I guess if you want different loops, you have to build dispatching to them out of `if`/`endif` at the top of the program/function?  Oh, and this machine doesn't have memory, *only* registers (and an unbounded callstack?), so the actual state is very small compared to a real machine.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm... thinking about it, all programs must eventually exit, either normally or when the C++ stack overflows. However, since the  "infinite loop" example wouldn't actually be an infinite loop because it crashes, I'm guessing that doesn't count.

Comment: Your assembly is kind of *magic*. `RET` and `CALL` rely on a meta-state. You should really formalize that first. Anyway, how big are your registers? If your state is finite, it's decideable if any program halts. If you ever step twice in the same state, then you'll loop forever. Note that there may be *a lot* of possible states. I think a `call` with the same value twice suffices to have an infinite loop. The other instructions don't seem to allow iteration at all.

Comment: @Margaret: call with the same value doesn't necessarily lead to an infinite loop if *other* registers are different.  e.g. you might do `call 1` inside an `if(--r3)` conditional that will eventually become false when r3 wraps around to zero again. But yes, having the return address stack separate from the rest of the architectural state, and inaccessible other than with ret, is super weird. As Ross points out, the actual interpreter will eventually overflow the C++ stack, and it's not clear if that's an intended limitation of the simulated ISA or if it's supposed to be Turing-Machine-like.

Comment: @PeterCordes Doesn't `call` zero the other regs?

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Oh yes, lol it does.  The text doesn't say so, but yes after looking at the C++ again, you're right.  That's even more totally different from how real ISAs work.  So I guess if you want to implement multiple sequential or nested loops, you have to encode all your state into that one number.  (mul / add to pack and mod / div to unpack).  So IDK if that makes it any less likely to be Turing-complete in any meaningful way, but it does reduce the size of usable state for looping.  Lacking any indirect addressing seems problematic, and so is the tiny state.

Comment: Anyway yes, just a hash table or bitmap of seen `call` args should be enough to detect infinite looping for this super-limited toy ISA.

Comment: @PeterCordes if the regs are unbounded it still is Turing complete, like you just proved. If they are not, you can decide "terminability". I'm writing a generic answer about it.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: In this C++ implementation, they're `int REG[RI::RI_MAX] {0};`.  Any given C++ implementation will have some finite width for `int`, no matter how large.

Comment: If the "halting problem solver" is designed specifically for a single program based on full knowledge of that program; then you can just write a solver that does literally nothing (e.g. for the code given, always says "never halts" because the answer is known before the solver was written). In that case the question becomes futile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to check to see if a program is stuck in an infinite loop in the general case is to check to see the program has entered the same state as previous state. If it has entered exactly the same state previously, then it must continue on executing in a loop returning to the same state over and over following the same sequence of steps. In real programs this essentially impossible because of the huge number of possible states the program can be in, but your assembly language only allows much more limited number of possible states.

Since your CALL instruction works just like invoking the program at the start and this is the only form of looping, this means that checking if the code enters the same state twice is simple.  A CALL instruction with a certain argument has the exact same effect as invoking the program with that argument as an input.  If the CALL instruction has the same argument as any previously executed CALL instruction or the program's input value, then it must continue executing in a loop endlessly returning to same state in the same sequence of steps.

In other words, the only state that needs to be checked is the R0 value at the start of the program.  Since this value is stored in a `int`, it can only have 2^32 possible values on any common C++ implementation, so it's reasonable and easy to brute force check see if a given program with a given input gets stuck in infinite loop.

In fact, it's possible to use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) of the return values to brute force check all possible inputs in O(N) time and O(N) space, where N is number of possible inputs.  There are various ways you could do this, but the way I would do it is to create three vectors, all with a number of elements equal to the number of possible inputs. The first vector is a `bool` (bit) vector that records whether or not a given input has been memoized yet, the second vector is also `bool` vector and it records whether a given input has been used already on the call stack, the second vector is an `int` vector that records the result and is used a linked list of input values to create a call stack to save space.  (In the code below these vectors are called, `is_memoized`, `input_pending` and `memoized_value` respectively.)

I'd take your interpreter loop and rewrite it to be non-recursive, something like this pseudo-code:

```
input = reg[R0]
if is_memoized[input]: 
    reg[R9] = memoized_value[input]
    return
input_pending[input] = true
memoized_value[input] = input  // mark the top of the stack

while true:
    for command in program:

        ...

        if command.op == CALL:
             argument = command.r2value

             if input_pending[argument]: 
                 // Since this input value is ready been used as input value 
                 // somewhere on the call stack this the program is about to enter
                 // an identical state as a previous state and so is stuck in
                 // a infinite loop.
                 return false  // program doesn't halt

             if is_memoized[argument]:
                 REG[R9] = memoized_value[argument]
             else:
                 memoized_value[argument] = input   // stack the input value

                 input = argument
                 REG = [input, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                 input_pending[input] = true
                 break  // reevaluate the program from the beginning.

        if command.op == RET:
              argument = command.r2value
              stacked_input = memoized_value[input]
              input_pending[input] = false
              if stacked_input == input:  // at the top of the stack
                  REG[R9] = argument
                  return true   // program halts for this input

              is_memoized[input] = true
              memoized_value[input] = argument
              input = stacked_input
              REG = [input, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
              break  // reevaluate the program from the beginning
```

You'd then call this interpreter loop for each possible input, something like this:

```
for i in all_possible_inputs:
     if not program.execute(input = i):  // the function written above
          print "program doesn't halt for all inputs"
          return
print "program halts for all inputs"
```

A recursive version should be faster since it doesn't have to reevaluate the program on each unmemoized CALL instruction in the program, but it would require hundreds of gigabytes of stack space in the worst case.  This non-recursive version only requires 17 GB of memory. Either way it's still O(N) space and time, you're just making one constant factor smaller and another bigger.

To get this execute in reasonable amount of time you'd also probably want to parse the code once, and execute some byte code representation instead.

Comment: Don't you only need 3 total bit-vectors (3x 512MiB for 32-bit `int` call state) to characterize a function for all inputs?  One known-to-halt, one known-to-infloop, and one "current starting value" one?  Once you find what happens with a given starting input, you OR its vector into the vector for whatever the result was.  (And you can use those known-result bitmaps while executing other tests, giving you memoization).  And you can bit-scan the OR of those vectors to find the next unknown state that needs checking.

Comment: Oh, no, that idea doesn't work.  A non-halting program can make some calls that do return, and you need the return *value*; that's what you're doing with memoization.  Nice!

Comment: interesting technique

Answer (score 2):

I take it you're looking for outside-the-box thinking.

Think of the halting problem this way. Turing proved programs are free from control. But why? Because the language has instructions to control execution. This means feasibly regulating and predicting execution in programs requires removing all control semantics from the language.

Even my collaborative process architecture doesn't accomplish that. It just forbids them because of the mess they make. It is still composed from a language which contains them. For example, you can use IF to break, return or continue but not for other operations. Function calls are illegal. I created such restrictions to achieve controllability. However not even a collaborative organization removes control structures from the language to prevent their misuse.

My architecture is online via my profile with a factorial example in my W article.

Answer (score 1):

If the program steps into the same configuration twice then it will loop forever.
This is also true for Turing Machines, it is just that the (infinite) input is part of the machine's configuration.
This is also the intuition behind the pumping lemmas.

What constitutes a configuration in your model?
Since you have no memory and no IO, a configuration is given by the content of the registers and the line number of the current instruction (i.e. the instruction pointer).

When do a configuration change?
After every instruction, sure. But in the case of a non-branching instruction, the configurations before and after it are *surely different* because even if the instruction is a NOP then line number changed.
In the case of a branch, the line number might be one that we've seen before (for a backwards branch), so that's where the machine could step into the same configuration.

The only jumping instruction of interest, to me, seems to be `call`. The `IF` like ones will always produce different configurations because they are not expressive enough to produce iteration (jump back and repeat).
How does `call` change a configuration? It sets the line number to 1 and all the registers (except `r0`) to zero.
**So the condition for a call to produce the same configuration reduces to having the same input.**

If you check, in the `call` implementation, if the operand value has already been used before (in the simulation) then you can tell that the program will loop forever.
If a register has size *n*, then the possible states are O(2<sup>n</sup>), which is generally a lot.
You must be prepared to give up after a (possible customizable) threshold.  Or in your case where your registers are `int`, most C++ implementations have 32-bit `int`, and modern machines can handle a 512MiB bitmap of 2^32 bits.  (`std::vector<bool>` implements a packed bitmap for example; index it with `unsigned` to avoid negative ints).  A hash table is another alternative (`std::unordered_set<int>`).  But if you used a wider type for your registers, the state would be too big to practically record every possible one and you would need some limit.  A limit is kind of built-in to your implementation as you will overflow the C++ callstack (C++ recursion depth) before seeing anywhere near 2^32 repeats of the machine being simulated.

If the registers are unbounded in their value, this reduces to the Halting Problem and thus undecideable in the general case.  (But as @Brendan says, you can still look for early repeats of the state; many programs will terminate or infinitely repeat in a simple way.)

If you change the `call` implementation to not zero out the other registers, you must fallback to check the whole configuration at the call site (and not just the operand).

---

**To check the termination of the program on every input you must proceed *non-deterministically* and *symbolically*.**
There are two problems: the branches and the input value.

It is a famous theorem that an NDTM can be simulated by a TM in an exponential number of steps w.r.t. the steps of the NDTM.
The only problematic instructions are the `IF` ones because they create non-determinism.
You can take several approaches:

- Split the simulation in two branches. One that executes the IF one that does not.
- Rewrite the code to be simulated to produce an exponential (in the number of branches) number of branch-free variants of the code. You can generate them lazily.
- Keep a tree of configurations, each branch in the program generating two children in the current node in the tree.

They are all equivalent.

The input value is not known, so it's hard to tell if a `call` ends up in the same configuration.
A possible approach is to record all the changes to the input register, for example you could end up with a description like "sub(add(add(R0, 1), 4), 5);".

This description should be easy to manipulate, as it's easy to see that in the example above `R0` didn't change because you get "sub(add(R0, 5), 5);" and then "R0;".
This works by relying on the laws of arithmetics, you must take care of inverse operations, identity elements (1 * a = a) and overflow.
Basically, you need to simplify the expression.
You can then check if the input has changed at a given point in the simulated time.

Comment: I added some practical ways to check for repeated configurations in the known-input case.  That's easy with only 32-bit `int` architectural state surviving through a `call`; a 512MiB `std::vector<bool>` bitmap of seen states should work nicely.  IDK if you left that out because it doesn't help for the *every*-input case, but it seems worth mentioning.

Comment: The every-input case could also be done with brute force iteration through every possible input, given the fixed-width state; a hash table of states is probably faster to clear back to empty between tests than munmap/mremap for a bitmap to get fresh lazily-zeroed pages.  For functions with few states there won't be many hash table entries before termination or repeat so it can be small and cleared quickly without system calls.

Comment: Re-parsing strings to execute every instruction is probably slow, but I wouldn't be surprised if a simple program like the OPs can be checked in a few (or tens?) thousand clock cycles per starting value on a modern x86, allowing brute force over all 2^32 possible starting values in hours or days, especially if you multithread it.  Exponential time complexity in the size of the input / architectural state rather than in the branching of the NDTM, but relatively easy to write.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks Peter, I left out some details because I'm lazy. It was an interesting problem, for me, mostly for the theory part (I've been already coded something similar in the past). I don't like the bruteforce approach too much, because it is resource-intensive, yet it is simple enough to be worth being considered.

Comment: Ross's idea for brute force is *much* better; memoization allows saving a lot of work.  Or with less memory: any state you see during an eventually-halting execution doesn't need to be checked as a starting value, so you just need one bitmap of definitely-halting.  You can merge your previously-seen bitmap into a definitely-halts bitmap after each trial, and thus avoid checking those start values even if you only memoize with a small LRU cache of actual return *values* for common call/ret values.

Comment: Starting with the *highest* input value might populate the definitely-halts bitmap nicely (except that one long first run might hit the C++ recursion-depth implementation limit).  And/or a small LRU memoization cache might do very well for many functions when testing sequentially increasing or decreasing inputs.  (Even with gaps for known-halting start values).  Ross's idea was full memoization but that's not necessary, and if you don't have the RAM for it then an LRU cache maybe be great.  Possibly with eviction weighted by how much work it took to fully eval?

Comment: @PeterCordes You can use memoization with every simulation approach. It's nothing new, it's an old, well known, and easy (compared to others) technique. Everyday programs will often not loop, trying to find a looping input will waste a lot of resources. Trying to prove termination (or refute it) as much as you can and then fallback to bruteforcing is probably better. Yet it will break in the near future when the OP will use 64 bit regs or change anything else. I like Ross' answer because it actually gives an implementation. That's what the OP is after, mine is more a note to my (lazy) self :)

Answer (score -3):

> How do I verify whether a program will enter into an infinite loop/recursion?

**In practice; the halting problem is trivial to solve.** It's only impossible in theory.

The reason people think that halting problem is impossible to solve is that the question is constructed as a false dilemma ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma ). Specifically; the question asks to determine if a program will always halt or will never halt; but there's a third possibility - sometimes halting (and sometimes not halting). For an example if this, imagine a program that asks the user if they want to halt forever or exit immediately (and correctly does what the user requested). Note that all sane applications are like this - they're not supposed to exit until/unless the user tells them to.

More correctly; in practice, there are 4 possibilities:

- runs until something external causes it to halt (power turned off, hardware failure, `kill -9`, ...)
- sometimes halts itself
- always halts itself
- indeterminate (unable to determine which of the 3 other cases it is)

Of course with these 4 possibilities, you can say you've created a "halting problem solver" just by classifying every program as "indeterminate", but it won't be a good solution. This gives us a kind of rating system - extremely good "halting problem solvers" rarely classify programs as "indeterminate", and extremely bad "halting problem solvers" frequently classify programs as "indeterminate".

So; how do you create a good "halting problem solver"? This involves 2 parts - generating control flow graphs ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph ) for each function and a call graph ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph ) for the whole program; and value tracking.

**Control Flow Graphs and Call Graph**

It's not that hard to generate a control flow graph for each function/procedure/routine, just by examining the control flow instructions (call, return, jump, condition branch); and not that hard to generate a call graph while you're doing this (just by checking if a node is already in the call graph when you see a call instruction and adding it if it's not there yet).

While doing this, you want to mark control flow changes (in the control flow graph for each function) as "conditional" or "not conditional", and you want to mark functions (in the call graph for the whole program) as "conditional" or "not conditional".

By analyzing the resulting graphs you can classify trivial programs as "runs until something external causes it to halt" or "always halts itself" (e.g. this is enough to classify OP's original code as "runs until something external causes it to halt"); but the majority of programs will still be "indeterminate".

**Value Tracking**

Value tracking is (trying) to keep track of the possible values that could be in any register/variable/memory location at any point in time. For example, if a program reads 2 unsigned bytes from disk into 2 separate variable you know both variables will have a value from 0 to 255. If those variables are multiplied you know the result will be a value from 0*0 to 255*255; if those variables are added you know the result will be a value from 0+0 to 255+255; etc. Of course the variable's type gives absolute maximum possible ranges, even for assembly (where there's no types) - e.g. (without knowing if it's signed or unsigned) you know that a 32-bit read from memory will return a value from -2147483648 to 4294967296.

The point of value tracking is to annotate conditional branches in the control flow graph for each function; so that you can use those annotations to help classify a program as something other than "indeterminate".

This is where things get tricky - improving the quality of a "practical halting problem solver" requires increasing the sophistication/complexity of the value tracking. I don't know if it's possible to write a perfect "halting problem solver" (that never returns "indeterminate") but I do know that it's possible to write a "halting problem solver" that is sufficient for almost all practical purposes (that returns "indeterminate" so rarely that nobody cares).

Comment: *I don't know if it's possible to write a perfect "halting problem solver"*.  Alan Turing *proved* that *isn't* possible, for a computer with unbounded storage (e.g. a Turing Machine with infinite tape).  If you allow external I/O, it's probably impossible for any real ISA.  The types of programs that are inevitably undecidable are brute-force searches for counterexamples to unproven theorems, or worse *provably unprovable* stuff.  e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Undecidable_generalizations.  (cf. Goedel's incompleteness theorem).

Comment: The question becomes whether a real machine with fixed width registers and address space can use unbounded external storage to implement truly arbitrary precision integers that can grow forever.  (Or if your idealized ISA has unbounded-size memory locations like a theoretical-CS [RAM machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine)...)  Otherwise you can in theory check for the machine state + external storage state matching an earlier state, because it will eventually repeat itself or halt in finite time if it can't address unbounded storage.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Alan Turing failed to recognize the false dilemma - his "program that does the opposite of what was predicted" can be classified as "sometimes halting".

Comment: @PeterCordes: The real question is whether anyone cares about "perfect". The reality is that no software is immune to all possible hardware failures and therefore no software can ever be perfect, and nobody cares.

Comment: The classical halting problem is for a specific Turing Machine with a specific initial state of the tape.  i.e. it's for a specific program with a specific sequence of I/O, in your terms.  Given that initial state, it will always do the same thing, not "sometimes" halt.  I think the disconnect between what you're talking about and Turing's proof is that the proof includes the full state and no variable I/O.

Comment: And yes, I considered upvoting your answer for the discussion about *practical* halting-detection, with a possibility of "can't tell".  As you say, the proof of undecidability in the general case doesn't mean *every* case is undecidable, and yes it's often easy.  If you fixed some of the mis-statements about the general case (where halting is data-dependent), it's very much non-trivial, it would be a good answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Doesn't "given that initial state, it will always do the same thing" disprove Alan's proof? ;-)

Comment: I think that's just a joke in the form of a question, in which case well played. :P